# UITableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle Method doesn't scroll tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to index my `UITableView` with following code

In my `ViewDidLoad`

```
arrayOfTableView = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25",@"26", nil];
```

And in my `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` Method

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20",@"21",@"22",@"23",@"24",@"25",@"26", nil];
    return tempArray;
}
```

And in my `sectionForSectionIndexTitle` Method

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    return index;
}
```

It's appear IndexBar beside of my tableview . However when i tap on IndexBar , it's doesn't scorll to there.

I have already test with `NSLog`, that event or not? It's event.

But don't scroll to tableView.

please help me to find out.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to check your     `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`  method.
Also you should implement this method (`tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`) only for table views with a section index list—which can only be table views created in the plain style (UITableViewStylePlain).